# I'm Having Trouble Connecting css to html

Tags: html, css

I can't get my html to link to my css. I've tried relativepath and absolute path and neither work. I use ctrl-u and the links dont show up in the html.

```
    <head>
     <meta charset="utf-8"/>
      <title> Jubilee Austin | Developer. </title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/main.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/normalize.css">
        <link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Source+Sans+Pro:400,700'rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
        <link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lora:400,700' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
   </head>
```

Comment: do you mean on your web server?

Comment: is the stylesheet available at that place on the server?

Comment: im going through the skillcrush html and css lessons and i have the files on  my computer there in a file named css in the file that my index.html is in.

Comment: can you tell where your `html` is located and where is your `CSS`?

Comment: The web uses (forward) slashes `/` as separators, not back-slashes `\\``  even when you're on windows. If the page you're working with is at `Users/Stone/Desktop/101-sample-code-17.08` then a relative URL of `css/main.css` should work.

Comment: the file i have my index html and cssfile in are the 101-sample-code file from skillcrush. is in the 101-sample-code file and the main.css and normalize.css are in the css file wich is in the 101-sample-code file.

Comment: _"... are in the css file ..."_ you mean in "the css _folder_" or "the css _directory_"

Comment: use this then:
`<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/main.css">`

Comment: please learn the difference between file and folder/directory

Comment: well i copied it from the OP's post, didn't notice it xD.. thnx @StephenP

Answer (score 1):

Try to make those filepaths to the stylesheets relative. If they are in a directory named "css" and that directory is next to your html file, this should work:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/main.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/normalize.css">
```

If the html file is in a separate directory next to the "css" directory, it would be:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../css/main.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../css/normalize.css">
```

Comment: he doesn't seem to be much familiar with even file locations

Answer (score -1):

You can't see the links to your css files when inspecting the page that the browser reads, is that right? To mee it sounds like some caching problem, I can't say at what level, it could also be at browser level. Have you tried to open it up in an other browser?

Comment: are you viewing the right file? Could it be that you've been saving the file somewhere else?

Comment: thats not it i only have the one html file if thats what your saying

Comment: @naui95 if you don't know what ya saying, then don't say it please

Comment: This isn't an answer in any case, it should have been a comment.

Answer (score -1):

Setting up an environment like this, similar to what you've described:

```
(Users/Myname/Desktop) +-- (some folder)
                       |
                       +-- (101-sample-code) --+-- [index.html]
                                               |
                                               +-- (css) --+-- [main.css]
                                                           |
                                                           +-- [normalize.css]

where a (directory) is in parentheses and a [file] is in brackets
```

These files work for me when opening the *index.html* file using the browser menu **File** > **Open File** (Chrome browser running on Mac OS X)
The *index.html* file is in the directory `101-sample-code` and the `css` directory is a *sibling* of the index.html file; a sub-directory of 101-sample-code.

The path `css/main.css` is therefore *relative* to the html source file.

```css
/* css/main.css */
p.main {
    padding: 1em;
    border: 1px dotted green;
}
p.main > code {
    background-color: #f0f0ff;
}

/* normalize.css */
p {
    font-family: "Lora";
}
p > code {
    font-family: "Source Sans Pro";
    border-bottom: 1px dotted #a0a0ff;
}

p.normal {
    padding: 1em;
    background-color: #f0fff0;
    border: 1px dotted black;
}
p.normal > code {
}
```

```html
<DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
     <meta charset="utf-8"/>
      <title> Jubilee Austin | Developer. </title>
       <!--
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="C:\Users\Stone\Desktop\101-sample-code-17.08\css\main.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="C:\Users\Stone\Desktop\101-sample-code-17.08\css\normalize.css">
       -->
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/main.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/normalize.css">

        <link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Source+Sans+Pro:400,700'rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
        <link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lora:400,700' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
    </head>

    <body>
        <h1>Heading</h1>

        <p>This paragraph is plain, it has no css class or ID attached to it.</p>

        <p class="normal">This is a <code>class="normal"</code> paragraph.</p>

        <p class="main">This is a <code>class="main"</code> paragraph.</p>
    </body>
</html>
```

If this is not like your directory tree you'll have to provide more details about how yours is set up, for example if you have an `html` directory and it has a *sibling* `css` directory the relative path from the html to the css file would be different — `href="../css/main.css"`